# Is it possible to override List accessors in Grails domain classes?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, dns

If I have a List in a Grails domain class, is there a way to override the addX() and removeX() accessors to it?

In the following example, I'd expect MyObject.addThing(String) to be called twice.  In fact, the output is:

> Adding thing: thing 2

```
class MyObject {
    static hasMany = [things: String]
    List things = []

    void addThing(String newThing) {
        println "Adding thing: ${newThing}"
        things << newThing
    }
}

class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
            MyObject o = new MyObject().save()
            o.things << 'thing 1'
            o.addThing('thing 2')
        }
        def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer:

Try using the built-in addToThings as documented here:

http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/addTo.html

Answer (score 2):

The method should be called leftShift(String), not addThing(), as documented on the Groovy operator overloading [page](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading).

Comment: Thanks, good to know.  Not sure how I can override the leftShift() method of the 'things' property though.

Comment: Thinking in a Java frame of mind, you could extend List and override it there. It might be more groovy (pun intended) to dynamically override the built in List implementation of leftShift(), but then _all_ of your List instances would follow this behaviour. Extend List?

Comment: Maybe I'm already thinking too much like it's Java.  I was hoping to perform e.g. validation in the addThing() method; would it be more groovy to create a Thing class which has constraints defined inside it?

Comment: It's addToThings BTW.  I'm not sure what type of validation you're trying to do but perhaps a separate Domain class is warranted.

Comment: Thanks, Matt - addToThings() is exactly what I'm looking for.  I'll consider a new Domain class too, depending on the usage.

Comment: I'm not sure what the convention is here: I'd like to accept Matt's answer, but it's only a comment.  Should I repost it as a response, edit the question or accept the answer this is attached toCan anyone advise?

Comment: Matt will likely see your comment and might add it as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @Matt you want to add "addToThings()" as the answer?

Comment: Sorry, only just saw this.  I created an answer.  Thanks for the nudge!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you expect `addThing()` to be called twice? Here's an explanation of your code

```
// things is a List, so this calls List.leftShift(Object) 
o.things << 'thing 1'

// o is an instance of MyObject, so this calls addThing()
o.addThing('thing 2')
```

So you're only calling `addThing()` once.